# Пример проекта на Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Начал изучать Web Api 2, поделитесь пожалуйста кто-нибудь ссылкой на исходники какого-нибудь большого проекта, на который можно смотреть как на образец, желательно чтоб в нем был swagger, разделение на несколько слоев логики и работы с данными, использовалась авторизация и аутентификация. Посмотрел на гитхабе, но ничего подобного не нашел...

Answer (score 1):

Вот, первый ответ из "Всезнающего Google": https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/